# Scraping filmography from a wikipedia page using nodejs and puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to get the filmography from Wikipedia. Using puppeteer, I'm selecting the filmography section from inspect element and copying the `XPath`. However, I'm not getting any film data.

---

`scrapers.js`

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer")

    const scrapeProduct = async (url) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(url)


    const [el] = await page.$x(`//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[1]/div[8]/div`)
    console.log("el=>", el)

    browser.close()
}


scrapeProduct("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werner_Herzog")
```

Here's what I'm getting in `console.log(el)`:

https://hastebin.com/usozakisen.yaml

Comment: Why would you try to scrape this in the first place? Wikipedia has a very decent _API_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`el` is an ElementHandle, not the content itself. You can try getting the `innerText` of that handle:

```
console.log(await el.evaluate(el => el.innerText));
```